# Bolt: saveContent updates values but doesn't actually save the record

Tags: bolt-cms

I'm trying to create new content with:

```
// Get suggestions template and update with values
$content = $this->app['storage']->getEmptyContent('suggestions');
$content->values['title'] = $title;
$content->values['description'] = $description;

// Save to db
$save = $this->app['storage']->saveContent($content);
```

`status` is set as `publish` in data returned from `getEmptyContent`.

When I visit the backend, I can see that the save status is `None`. How can I actually create it so that it is published?.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like it could be a bug since as far as I can remember some value should make it through to status by default. One thing to check, in your contenttypes.yml file for suggestions you can also add a default_status eg:

```
default_status: publish
```

If you still have no luck then raise an issue on Github.